# Equatable object not updated when content updated

Tags: swiftui, onchange, equatable

I'm trying to wrap my head around how SwiftUI deals with Equatable, and I can't understand why onChange doesn't seem to trigger when an equatable object is updated.

Below is an example of what I'm confused about. If you use the slider, the text updates just fine, but the OnChange doesn't trigger. It only triggers if you change the number of objects in the Array.

PointAnnotation is equatable by default, but to double-check it's comparing latitude I've also made it adhere to equatable manually. Doing so doesn't change the behavior.

What am I missing?

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var controller = Controller()
        @State private var change:Bool = false
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Obj 0 lat: \(controller.object.annotations[0].coordinate.latitude)")
                    .padding()
                
                Text("Obj changed: \(change ? "true" : "false")")
                
                Slider(value: $controller.object.annotations[0].coordinate.latitude, in: (0...10))
            }
            .onChange(of: controller.object, perform: { value in change = true })
        }
    }

    class Controller:ObservableObject {
        @Published var object = Object()
    }

    struct Object:Equatable {
        var annotations:[MapAnnotation] = MapAnnotation.exampleArray
    }

    import MapKit

    class MapAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation {
        var id:String = UUID().uuidString
    }

    extension MapAnnotation {
        static var exampleArray:[MapAnnotation] = [ MapAnnotation(), MapAnnotation(), MapAnnotation() ]
    }
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for the involved classes. The only class in the hierarchy that implements `==` to conform to `Equatable` is NSObject so what you should do is to override `==` for your annotation class

Comment: `controller.object` is not changed because modified instance of annotation `$controller.object.annotations[0]` is a pointer, which remains same when you change its properties (latitude in this case). You need to rethink your model.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, this will not help - pointer in array will remain the same.

Comment: How would I "rethink my model" in this case? Use case is that object contains a set of annotations on a map, and when i drag one of them on the map I want the object to update so I can save it to firebase. As far as I know MKPointAnnotation can't be changed to a struct, so would I have to make my own struct and manually sync values from MKPointAnnotation when I change the map?.

Comment: This issue is not related to UIKit or SwiftUI, when you are going use UIKit classes in a View, there is no way make UIKit report their class changes to View or SwiftUI, the only way is that you override some functions and codes to putting custom Publisher in your custom class then you can observe those data as well. More info: you have to manually write some code for what you need, like using didSet or updating a Publisher on each action in class. some thing like that! the issue is you are facing is the same in Timer or AudioPlayer, . . .

Comment: Why not `Slider(value: $controller.object.annotations[0].coordinate.latitude, in: (0...10), onEditingChanged: { change = true })`?